# A Language Belonges to PSPACE

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, space-complexity

> Let $A,B$ be two languages, for which we know:
>
> - $A \in PSPACE$
> - $A\le_LB$
>
> Can we conclude from the above that $B \in PSPACE$ ?

I think the answer is no, however I don't know how to prove it. I guess I have to write a reduction that proves otherwise, but how?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: LOGSPACE$\subseteq $PSPACE, and a logspace reduction has enough power to decide membership for a language in LOGSPACE.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 2):

No. 
Note that given languages $A,B$ and a reduction $A\le_L B$, you get that $B$ is at least as hard as $A$, but that's about it.

You can contradict the above statement with the following extreme:

Take $A = \{0\}$, then $A\in \text{PSPACE}$, and take $B= H_{TM}\cup\{0\}$.

Define $f$ to be the following reduction $A \le_L H_{TM}\cup\{0\}$ (we can assume that $1\notin H_{TM}$):

$$f(0) = 0$$ $$\forall x\in \Sigma^*\setminus\{0\}  . f(x)=1$$.

Clearly $f$ works in logarithmic space, but $B$ is clearly not in $\text{PSPACE}$. In fact, it isn't even in $\text{R}$.